# React Native. Native Android component is not rendered

Tags: android, react-native

I want to add a component from Android to React Native.
But it does not render and does not have dimensions.
How can I fix this and display the component?
Code classes to connect the component.
I used guides and other people's examples.

**UPD:**
There was an error:
REACT_CLASS = "RCTImageView";
It remains from the rest of the attempts.
Changed back to CustomView - did not help.

CustomViewManager.java:

```
public class CustomViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<TextView> {

public static final String REACT_CLASS = "CustomView";

@Override
public String getName() {
    return REACT_CLASS;
}

@Override
public TextView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext context) {

    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setText("Текст");
    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tv.setWidth(100);
    tv.setHeight(100);
    return tv;

  }
}
```

CustomViewPackage.java:

```
public class CustomViewPackage implements ReactPackage {

@Override
public List<ViewManager>
createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Arrays.<ViewManager>asList(
            new CustomViewManager()
    );
}

@Override
public List<NativeModule>
createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

}
```

MainApplication.java:

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(),
      new CustomViewPackage()
  );
}
```

CustomTextView.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
   requireNativeComponent
} from 'react-native';

module.exports = requireNativeComponent('CustomView');
```

App.js:

```
export default class App extends Component {
render() {
  return (
    <View 
      style={ styles.container }
    >
      <CustomView/>
    </View>
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It was necessary to set the flex dimensions.

In the CustomView component, you had to pass style = {{flex: 1}}

Comment: Consider commenting or  include more details with your answer

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you wrote acceptable CSS. Don't use like '12pt', '12', and any font-family CSS which are not installed in our app. If your android simulator is breaking in Expo editor please check all the components CSS agiain.